# How do i convert a string to double in java when the string contains math functions?

Tags: java, android

i have a string with a math function, like  "35+20". i want a new double variable that takes in the result of the math function i.e, 55.0 How do i achieve this? this is actually for android, i'm making a calculator..

Comment: You may find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Answer (score 0):

Manually parse the string and do a calculation at each operator symbol. It will get more complicated when dealing with brackets, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it yourself, you'll probably want to implement the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

There are also some libraries that handle it for you.

https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you are working on a calculator I am assuming that you might not only be interested in just the + operation but on a bunch of other stuffs too.
You can look in to open source GitHub project linked below which provides the JAVA implementation for the stuff you are trying to do https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx 
which can give you a good set of functionality that you desire.
This project takes in a string as an expression and the returns the result in BigDecimal format.
You can always extend it and tweek it to custom suite you needs.